# Connect4 in Python - Pieces doesn't drop into the board

Tags: python, python-3.x, connect-four

I'm writing Connect4 in Python. My problem is the function of player_one and player_two don't seem to be working, so the no piece is drop onto the board after player was asked to give input. I also wonder if my code to return the board after player has dropped is correct; I suspect that my present code doesn't return the board updated with a player's piece but being new, I'm not sure what to do.

Please take a look!

```
def field(field):
    for w in range(14):
        if w % 2 == 0:
            usable_w = int(w/2)
            for h in range(15):
                if h % 2 == 0:
                    usable_h = int(h/2)
                    if h != 14:
                        print(field[usable_h][usable_w], end="")
                    else:
                        print(" ")
                else:
                    print("|", end="")
        else:
            print("_"*13)


PlayField = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
             [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
field(PlayField)


def player_one(field):
    MoveColumn = int(input("Enter the column 1 - 7\n"))
    MoveRow = 6
    for row in PlayField:
        if MoveColumn >= 1 and MoveColumn <= 7:
            if PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] == " ":
                    PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] = "X"
                    break
            MoveRow -= 1
            return field(PlayField)
        else:
            print("Column outside range, please enter valid move")

def player_two(field):
    MoveColumn = int(input("Enter the column 1 - 7\n"))
    MoveRow = 6
    for row in PlayField:
        if MoveColumn >= 1 and MoveColumn <= 7:
            if PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] == " ":
                    PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] = "O"
                    break
            MoveRow -= 1
            return field(PlayField)
        else:
            print("Column outside range, please enter valid move")

def launch_play():
    while True:
        Player = 1
        print("Player's turn", Player)
        player_one(field)
        player_two(field)

launch_play()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `player_...` functions contain suitable statements, but in an unsuitable order; and since they operate on the global `PlayField`, returning it is pointless. Besides that, it's ugly having two nearly identical functions. A rearranged variant where the only difference between player one and two is passed as an argument (instead of the useless `field`) works as you expect:

```
def player(xo):
    while (MoveColumn := int(input("Enter the column 1 - 7\n"))) < 1 or \
                                                      MoveColumn > 7:
        print("Column outside range, please enter valid move")
    MoveRow = 6
    for row in PlayField:
        if PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] == " ":
            PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] = xo
            field(PlayField)
            break
        MoveRow -= 1
```

In your `launch_play` loop you can now call

```
        player('X')
        player('O')
```

Now it's up to you to complete the program by checking when the game is over.

Comment: Hi Armali, what if I don't want the players' turn to change if they don't enter a valid move?

Comment: There's more than one way. I changed the function accordingly. Surely you could have come up with something similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm figuring out how just by putting the MoveRow variable under a while loop solve all the issues. Appreciate it if you could explain.

Comment: I would be willing to explain, but I don't understand what you'd like to be explained. If by _the MoveRow variable_ you mean the assignment `MoveRow = 6`: that's not in the `while` loop (which loops until a valid move is entered), but only after that loop. And what do you mean by _all the issues_?

Comment: Yes, I mean the assignment MoveRow = 6 was originally before a for loop. Your modification put it after a while loop, and it solves two very important issues for me, 1. the pieces fall into the board, 2. the pieces stacks on each other. Why is that?

Comment: These issues were not solved by moving `MoveRow = 6`; they were solved by removing the `return` (which was done in the first loop cycle if the piece couldn't be placed in the bottom row).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two solutions (before you modified the codes) to prevent players' turn from changing, but which couldn't work:

```
def player(xo):
    while MoveColumn := int(input("Enter the column 1 - 7\n")):
    MoveRow = 6
    for row in PlayField:
        if PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] == " ":
            PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] = xo
            field(PlayField)
            break
            Return True
        MoveRow -= 1
    else:
       print("Column outside range, please enter valid move")
       Return False

def launch_play():
    while True:
        Player = 'X'
        print("Player's turn", Player)
        player('X')
        Player = '0'
        print("Player's turn", Player)
        player('0')

launch_play()
```

The other solution is to introduce player variables in the player functions (also didn't work) :

```
 def player(xo):
    while MoveColumn := int(input("Enter the column 1 - 7\n")):
    MoveRow = 6
    Player = 'X'
    for row in PlayField:
        if PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] == " ":
            PlayField[MoveColumn-1][MoveRow] = xo
            field(PlayField)
            break
        MoveRow -= 1
        Player = '0'
    else:
       print("Column outside range, please enter valid move")
```

Comment: Look at your "solutions" - you'll see that the column validity check is missing; add that.